# Why did java designers impose a mandate that if obj1.equals(obj2) then obj1.hashCode() MUST Be == obj2.hashCode()

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Why did java designers impose a mandate that 
if obj1.equals(obj2) then 
    obj1.hashCode() MUST Be == obj2.hashCode()

Comment: Because that's pretty much a requirement for the hash code to be useful in hashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that's not baked into the language - you could technically have objects whose equals() method does not check the hashcode but you'll get pretty peculiar results.

In particular if you put a bunch of these objects into a HashMap or HashSet the map/set will use the hashCode() method to determine whether the objects may be duplicates - so you can have a situation where a collection will store 2 objects you've defined as equals (which should never happen)  because they're each returning different hashCodes.

Comment: Not without violating the contract of hashCode() you can't.

Comment: That's the point of the question, I think - the contract is explicitly documented, but there's nothing prohibiting you from breaking it. I've seen this break in exactly this way in production code.

Answer (score 9):

Because a HashMap uses the following algorithm to find keys quickly:

- get the `hashCode()` of the key in argument
- deduce the bucket from this hash code
- compare every key in the bucket with the key in argument (using `equals()`) to find the right one

If two equal objects didn't have the same hash code, the first two steps of the algorithm wouldn't work. And it's those two first steps that make a HashMap very fast (O(1)).

Answer (score 4):

There is no mandate. It is a good practice since this is a required condition if your objects are meant to be used in hash based data structures like HashMap/HashSet etc.

Comment: It all depends on what you call a "mandate". But the contract is clearly specified, and you're supposed to obey the contract. Not doing it is a bug.

Comment: @Varun It is a clear must, not just a good practice. See "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result." from [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

Comment: @JB Nizet: Yes, agree it is a bug, but my intent was to understand why the designers chose to set that contract!

Comment: @SeshumadhavChaturvedula: see my answer. My comment was for Varun. I disagree with him. There *is* a mandate, IMHO.

Comment: @SeshumadhavChaturvedula From the same link, read that the steps are mentioned as "general contract" if you are implementing hashCode(). Say if you are using your objects only in an ArrayList, you need to implement only equals method but you need not implement hashCode() and if you don't implement hashCode() the default implementation will produce different results. Now is it a bug? No. hashCode() is used for hash based data structures and thus this rule is mandatory if the objects are being held in such collections.

Comment: @Varun If you don't use it in code that uses the `hashCode()` method, there will not be misbehaviour. But it is still a bug, as they stated this requirement (it's not a "note on good practice"). It's a bug by definition, not by symptom.

Answer (score 1):

Because hashcodes are used to quickly determine if two objects are not equal.

Comment: No they're not. They are used to quickly determine if they might be equal. There is specific wording in the contract that makes your statement incorrect.

Comment: if their hashcodes are equal the objects might be equal, if their hashcodes are not equal the objects are not equal. So you can't determine the objects are equal by hashcode, but you can determine the objects are not equal by hashcode.

Comment: No. See the Javadoc I referred you to: "It is *not* required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables." If what you claim was true, Long.hashCode() would be unimplementable, ditto String.hashCode() for Strings longer than 4 bytes.

Comment: My statement is saying that if 2 objects do not have the same hashcode they are not equal; can we agree on that ?

Comment: That's not what your answer says at all. They are not used in the way your answer describes. They are used to locate a bucket of equally-(re-)hashcoded items, one of which may be the item being looked for. They are not used to establish inequality, because inequality is of no interest in that process.

Comment: yeah well, if they (the hashcodes) are not equal they aren't in the same bucket and otherwise they are.

Answer (score 0):

Its sort of two steps matching to improve performance.

First Step:  calculate hashcode()

Second Step: calculate equals()

Its because if you put your objects as keys in collections like hashmap, your keys will be compared first on hashcode() method if it finds matching hashcode it then goes on further to calculate equals().

**Its like indexing for better search performance**

Comment: Just looked up put()s implementation in http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html. If hashCode() was not forced to be equal, then HashMap would store two entries for the same key(same bcoz equals() was true), which is against spirit of HashMap. SteveB's answer seems appropriate to me. It seems more about correctness rather than performance